# What is the size limit of a 3d model for converting it into arrAsset?

Tags: unity-game-engine, fbx, azure-remote-rendering

I am currently trying to use Azure's remote rendering tools. And my model is about 580MB (it's an FBX file). I attempted to convert it into arrAsset but it say: "the conversion process exceeded system resources. It's possible the asset is too large.", even though I tried to change the performance from standard to premium, it did not solve the problem.

Does anyone know the maximum size the 3d model should have so that it is converted successfully ?

(Also, I would be glad to hear some tips about how to reduce the size of my FBX file)

Thank you in advance.
[result of the conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlCDP.png)

Answer (score 0):

you've also created a support case to Microsoft developer support. my colleague will help you further on that channel.

there isn't a particular file limit, but there are some limits covered in our docs in regards of server size, primitives limit and max dimensions of a single texture.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/remote-rendering/reference/limits#geometry
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/remote-rendering/reference/vm-sizes
- FAQ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/remote-rendering/resources/troubleshoot#common-client-side-issues

Comment: Yes, I checked the server size and I am using the premium server, not the standard one. I not sure if the issue is the model I submitted :/

Comment: I'll add your GitHub issue here for reference https://github.com/Azure/azure-remote-rendering/issues/97

Answer (score 0):

Please don't post the same question in multiple places.

The problem has been adressed in this GitHub issue:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-remote-rendering/issues/97

To wrap this up:

- Generally, there is no file size limit for conversion. However, FBX files can describe data in such a way, that even a small file may generate lots of triangles and thus take a long time to process or even exceed the system resources (RAM) of the machine that does the conversion.
- Additionally, in this case there was a bug that meant the system would allocate much more memory than was really needed. This has been dealt with, as mentioned in that ticket.

Also, conversion is not tied to the rendering VM, at all. You do not run a conversion on a Standard or Premium VM. This distinction is only needed for rendering the converted result. During conversion you don't need a rendering VM, at all.